# Am I the only person seeing this colour scheme?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently saw this colour scheme in the main site under Newest Questions:

[image]

As you can see, the first question is yellow.

I've never seen this before. And this is happening only with this question, even after some time:

[image]

What is the reason of this unusual colour scheme on only one question suddenly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Questions which have your "favorite" tags are highlighted in yellow in most listings. If you don't explicitly choose favorite tags (using the desktop site), the system chooses some for you based on what tags you are most active in. So evidently the system has decided to designate either [quantum-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) or [wavefunction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wavefunction) as a favorite tag for you. (More likely the latter since you say you haven't seen this before, and [wavefunction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wavefunction) is more rare.)

Comment: How can I change my preferences?

Comment: See [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

Comment: Thanks for the help!